# How to implement monotonic functions in pine-script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Let's say we want a function that returns true or false if a data type from pine is monotonic increase. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("monotonic increase function", overlay = false)

n = input.int(5)

f_is_mon_inc(float[] _set) =>
    bool _is_mon_inc = true
    _size = array.size(_set)
    if _size > 1
        _maxval = array.max(_set)
        _minval = array.min(_set)
        _firstval = array.get(_set, _size - 1)
        _lastval = array.get(_set, 0)
        if _firstval == _minval and _lastval == _maxval
            for i = _size - 2 to 0
                _val_i = array.get(_set, i)
                _val_prev = array.get(_set, i + 1)
                if _val_i < _val_prev
                    _is_mon_inc := false
                    break
        else
            _is_mon_inc := false
    _is_mon_inc

var float[] set = array.new_float()

array.unshift(set, close)

if array.size(set) > n
    array.pop(set)

is_mon_inc = f_is_mon_inc(set)

plot(is_mon_inc ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would be so kind to further explain why unshift and pop? @rumpypumpydumpy

Comment: The use of the array isn't strictly necessary. You could just work with a loop and use the historical operator with a normal time series variable (ie `close[n]`). If n is very large however you may run into the max bars lookback error and using an array and built in array functions avoids this and also makes it a little more straightforward. Using `unshift/pop` instead of `push/shift` is just personal preference. unshift/pop will order by index similarly to the historical operator's use so that `close[1]` is the same source value as `array.get(set, 1)`